# Dispatch custom event during customer account create in guest checkout

Tags: event-observer, customer, onepage-checkout, customer-account

Where do I dispatch my custom event during customer account create in guest checkout.

Comment: Do you mean to ask "how do I configure an observer to consume some event when a customer creates an event during guest checkout?"

Comment: yes @benmarks ur absolutely right!

Comment: @benmarks have any solution for my ques? :(